# How to recursively ask to input while the input is not valid?

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion, input

I want to check, if the input isn't a number then it will recursively ask to input again, until it received a number. Here's my current code. FYI : Looping is forbidden.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int input(int *n){
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if (!(x>=-32768 && x<=32767)){
        printf("not valid, try again.");
        return input(n);
    }
    else{
        *n = x;
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2;
    int *n = &num1;
    int *m = &num2;
    input(n);
    input(m);
    printf("%d %d\n",num1,num2);

    return 0;

}
```

thx in advance.

Comment: Isn't your code working?

Comment: @MathewsMathai nope, it gives me infinite recursion.

Comment: @EdwinHarly You need to check the return value from `scanf`. A return value of 1 means the user typed a number. Any other value means that your program needs to exit. Either that or you need to flush the input stream. In any case, it's a really bad idea to use recursion for this. A simple loop will do.

Comment: @user3386109 sadly I was told not to use any loop in this case, that's why I'm using recursion.

Comment: @user3386109 what do you mean by "off-topic" ??? I'm talking about recursion here not looping, if you can't provide an answer, just stay out of here.

Comment: I wonder why is it going to infinite recursion.

Comment: Your code works perfectly on gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: Maybe you should use `gcc -S *.c`, and post your assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you should not use recursion in this case, do a check in a `loop`  as with

```
Do{
   /* read the number*/
  }while(!condition_to_be_valid);
```

Comment: You should stick to the OPs Question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly on gcc 4.8.4, you can try other compiler, such as `gcc`.

Comment: The OP needs to be recursive, he/she mentioned that in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static int num1, num2;
```

Also, it will be very helpful if you can post the assembly code. You can get it using `gcc -S`